# equivalent metric

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let $(X; d)$ and $(Y; d')$ be metric spaces, and let $f : X \to Y$ be continuous. Define
$df (x; y) = d(x; y) + d'(f(x); f(y))$ for $x, y \in X$. Show that $df$ is a metric on $X$ that is equivalent to $d$.

I think this prove need two directions:
In one direction, assume $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x_0$ by metric $d$.
so need to show $\{x_n\}$ also converges to $x_0$ by metric $df$.
Then I get stuck.
Any help?

Comment: Hint: Use: $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

How to show that $d_f$ is a metric. First, it takes values in $[0,+\infty)$ as $d$ does. Then separation follows from the separation of $d$. Symmetry is clear thanks to the symmetry of $d$. Triangular inequality is an easy exercise using the triangular inequality for $d$.

In a more pedantic way: $d_f$ is the sum of the metric $d$ and the pseudometric $d(f(x),f(y))$. Hence it is a metric.

Now equivalence. Since $d \leq d_f$, every converging sequence for $d_f$ converges for $d$ to the same point. Conversely, if $d(x_n,x_0)\longrightarrow 0$, then by continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, we have $d(f(x_n),f(x_0))\longrightarrow 0$. I think you can conclude.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!